# How to setup a domain to AWS S3 Bucket Website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I bought a domain (.app) at OVH.com. My website is hosted on Amazon Webservices - S3 Bucket. I have configured a bucket and my page is public visible at http://www.HERE-MY-NAME.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.

I want to connect my domain to my AWS hosting. I created a "Hosted Zone" on Route 53 Service. I have created an "A" record that points to my bucket (see screenshot). On the OVH, I changed the DNS to: ns-1450.awsdns-53.org and ns-1838.awsdns-37.co.uk.

Now when I visit my domain without "www." appears an error: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. When I visit with "www." then appears "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

What am I doing wrong?

[settings on amazon webservices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9XP7.png)

Comment: Did you follow the steps on [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)?